# Auditd not capturing the directory deletion event

Tags: linux, logging, audit-trail

I have given the following rules in the auditd configuration.

```
  audit_rules: |
    -w /etc/group -p wa -k identity
    -w /etc/passwd -p wa -k identity
    -w /etc/gshadow -p wa -k identity
    -w /etc/shadow -p wa -k identity
    -w /etc/security/opasswd -p wa -k identity
    -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S open,creat,truncate,ftruncate,openat,open_by_handle_at -F exit=-EACCES -k access
    -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S open,creat,truncate,ftruncate,openat,open_by_handle_at -F exit=-EPERM -k access
    -a always,exit -F dir=/home -F uid=0 -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -C auid!=obj_uid -F key=power-abuse
    -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S setuid -F a0=0 -F exe=/usr/bin/su -F key=elevated-privs
    -a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S setuid -F a0=0 -F exe=/usr/bin/su -F key=elevated-privs
    -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S setresuid -F a0=0 -F exe=/usr/bin/sudo -F key=elevated-privs
    -a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S setresuid -F a0=0 -F exe=/usr/bin/sudo -F key=elevated-privs
    -a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve -C uid!=euid -F euid=0 -F key=elevated-privs
    -a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S execve -C uid!=euid -F euid=0 -F key=elevated-privs
```

While this is capturing file deletion successfully, it is not capturing folder deletion,renaming or modification.
Why is it so?. Do I need to change the rules for folder monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

From your rules, I can see that you are watching the directory /home

```
-a always,exit -F dir=/home -F uid=0 -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -C auid!=obj_uid -F key=power-abuse
```

The -F dir field sets a rule that watches all the files inside the directory. Instead, you want to use -F path field.

```
-a always,exit -F path=/home -F uid=0 -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -C auid!=obj_uid -F key=power-abuse
```

the path field only watches the inode that the directory occupies.

According to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/audit.rules.7.html, it reads "Using syscall rules you can choose between path and dir which is against a specific inode or directory tree respectively."